# Why does this command sometimes throw array bounds exceptions when it contains no arrays

Tags: vb.net, file-copying, filesystemobject

I have a process that loops through an array which is a list of PDF filenames, for each file it must write a template PDF which is stored in the same folder as the exe and copy this to a network share as "pdffilename"~001.pdf and then copy the data file from an S3 bucket to the network share as "pdffilename"~002.pdf. In some cases, the file won't exist but we would still need the separator and sometimes the code would just be writing multiple separators (~001) and no data files but when this happens I randomly get failures in writing the separator pdf.

This works fine when running on my laptop through VS but when I deploy the app up to our application server it fails when there are lots of missing files.

```
If sFile(0) <> "999-Envelopes" Then
    Try
        boxTriggerReqd = True
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("doc_sep.pdf", OutputFolder & "\" & Replace(oFileName, "~002.pdf", "~001.pdf"), True)
        Log.writeline("Document Separator written:" & vbTab & OutputFolder & "\" & Replace(oFileName, "~002.pdf", "~001.pdf"))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Call EndTask(ex.Message, "Unable to transfer Document separator", 11)
    End Try
Else
    envTriggerReqd = True
End If
Try
    dlResponse = s3client.GetObject(GetFile)
    With dlResponse
        .WriteResponseStreamToFile(OutputFolder & "\" & oFileName)
        .Dispose()
    End With
    Log.WriteLine("Data file written:" & vbTab & vbTab & OutputFolder & "\" & oFileName)

Catch ex As Exception
    results.WriteLine(sFile(1))
    Call EndTask(ex.Message, targetFile, 12)
    results.Flush()
End Try
```

The error log shows

```
 ****** S3 PULL ******
 Index was outside the bounds of the array.
 Unable to transfer Document separator
 ****** S3 PULL ******
```

Where it has called EndTask contains the "Unable to transfer Document separator" so it has happened in one of three commands

I'm assuming its the CopyFile command but there is no reference to an array in any of those three. Is it possibly a memory error on the server itself?

Comment: Did you look at the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: What is `sFile(0)` ?

Comment: sFile is a split of the 2 parts of the filename, first part identifies whether it needs separators, filenames that start "999-Envelopes" don't need separators.

Comment: Dim sFile = manifileList(file).split("#") where manifileList is the array containing the list of filenames

Comment: Is this possibly a memory error on the server itself? The code would be holding arrays at the time but not actually using them in that part of the code